# How to customize a 404 page in CODEIGNITER while performing the is_ajax_request function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have done the costume on $route["404_override"], and loaded my own 404 page.

The problem is, why when I do a 404 page call with the function 'show_404 ();' This page still displays the Codeigniter standard page.

in Exceptions.php

```
<?php
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function show_404($page = ''){
    redirect('404','refresh');
    exit;
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: if you add 404 page default controller in `route.php` then you don't need to add redirection code. you just create 404 controller to call view and change layout in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple, why do you do the hard things if you can still do the easy thing?

Delete MY_Exceptions file, and do edit on default file 404 codeigniter file, in `views/errors/html/error_404.php`

Comment: Thank you for your input :), Your words are quite motivated :D